Transaction sign using tronpy failure
I want to transfer TRX from address 1 to address 2 but keep receiving this error.
Chat gpt doesn`t help it just keeps giving me the same code sample.
It looks like there is no atribute 'sign'. Is there a way to fix it?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\vladi\PycharmProjects\sweeper\send.py", line 29, in 
send_trx(sender_private_key, from_address, to_address, amount)
File "C:\Users\vladi\PycharmProjects\sweeper\send.py", line 15, in send_trx
txn_signed = txn.sign(private_key)
^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'TransactionBuilder' object has no attribute 'sign'
from tronpy import Tron
from tronpy.keys import PrivateKey

def send_trx(sender_private_key, from_address, to_address, amount):
    # Initialize Tron client
    client = Tron()

    # Create a PrivateKey object
    private_key = PrivateKey(bytes.fromhex(sender_private_key))

    # Create a transaction
    txn = client.trx.transfer(from_address, to_address, amount * 1e6)  # amount in TRX, convert to Sun

    # Sign the transaction
    txn_signed = txn.sign(private_key)

    # Broadcast the transaction
    result = txn_signed.broadcast()
    txid = result.get('txid')
    print(f'Transaction sent, ID: {txid}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Enter transaction details
    sender_private_key = 'your_private_key'  # Sender's private key
    from_address = 'sender_address'          # Sender's address
    to_address = 'recipient_address'         # Recipient's address
    amount = 1.0                             # Amount in TRX

    send_trx(sender_private_key, from_address, to_address, amount)


